# Magento 1.9: Custom category field for an image not showing on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, category, image, frontend

I want to add a picture on top of category name in frontend. I tried creating a custom field for the category and adding a picture that way. I can see the custom field from admin, but I can't see anything I type in the custom textarea on my frontend category name. I tried flushing cache and reindexing data. I also tried adding in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml this code:

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute()): ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when i added it all my products disappeared and I still coundn't see changes to my category name.

Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: Please don't post non-answers to try to bump the question. That's an abuse of the system.

Comment: You can find answer by link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719296/how-to-add-a-custom-image-field-to-a-category-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that programming is necessary to add an image above the items in a category. Here is a simple solution that may meet your requirements.

1. Create a Static CMS block with your image in it. Menu Item  **CMS -> Static Blocks**
2. Update the Display Settings for the category where you want to image to appear and add the block.

Here is the navigation:

1. Catalog -> Manage Categories
2. Select The category you want to update
3. Select the Display Settings Tab
4. Set the **Display Mode** to **Static Block and Products**
5. Set the **CMS Block** to the Static Block you created for the category.

That's it you are done. Maybe clear the cache if you change does not appear immediately.

Magento is very versatile out of the box with lots of built-in features.